# Java and .NET/PowerShell producing different UTF-8 bytes

Tags: java, .net, powershell, utf-8

am getting grey hair over this.
I need to convert strings in PowerShell to UTF-8. My reference code is in Java (and works as intended with the bigger application), so I need to reproduce what it does.

In Java, I do:

```
    private static final char[] HEX_ARRAY = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();

    public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
        for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
            int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = HEX_ARRAY[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = HEX_ARRAY[v & 0x0F];
        }
        return new String(hexChars);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(bytesToHex("aöß".getBytes("UTF8")));
    }
```

which outputs **`61C3B6C39F`**.

In PowerShell, I do

```ps1
Write-Output $(([System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::New($false, $true).getBytes("aöß") | ForEach-Object ToString X2) -join '')
```

which outputs **`61C383C2B6C383C5B8`**

Why are they different? How can I make the PowerShell encoding match the Java one?

I would be very grateful for any insights!

Best
eDude

**EDIT**: Ok, now I am more confused. When running the above command in the PowerShell 5.1 console, it works as expected. When putting it into a script file and executing that, it does not.

**EDIT 2**: More info, if the script file is saved in UTF-8 encoding, the error appears. If it is saved in another encoding (e.g. Notepad++'s ANSI), it works. Why is the encoding of the script file changing the behavior of the script itself? How can I prevent this and make sure to get consistent results?

Comment: Looks like the powershell is twice encoded

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this, I get `61c3b6c39f` in both PowerShell 5.1, 7.1 and 7.2. Which version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting your script file to `UTF-8-BOM` encoding in Notepad++ and running it. PowerShell 5's default encoding is `Western European (Windows)` (`windows-1252`) so when there's no BOM in your script file it reads it as UTF-16, thus the double-length string.

Default encoding in PowerShell 7 is `UTF-8`, so it shouldn't be a problem.

You can check the default encoding for the different powershell versions like this:

```
PS> [System.Text.Encoding]::Default
```

You can also specify the required characters to avoid this issue in files without a BOM:

```
$str = [char]0x0061 + [char]0x00F6 + [char]0x00DF

Write-Output $(([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($str) | ForEach-Object ToString X2) -join '')
```

Comment: Thank you, that works! Still a weird that the encoding of the script file itself modifies its behavior...